# Getting HTML table values. Sending them with Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I need to get all table values and send them to my controller for processing!

Here is my table:

```
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get get this 6 values in to array and send them with ajax to my script for processing?

Edit: Something like when form is submitted with ajax using data:

```
serialize("#form")
```

Comment: create json from table and send it with ajax as parameter

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var values = $('#test td')  // Find all <td> elements inside of an element with id "test".
    .map(function(i, e){    // Transform all found elements to a list of jQuery objects...
        return e.innerText; // ... using the element's innerText property as the value.
    })
    .get();                 // In the end, unwrap the list of jQuery objects into a simple array.
```

[Working fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/uuCKM/)

---

ES6 makes this one look a bit more elegant:

```
let values = $('#test td')
    .map((index, element) => element.innerText)
    .get();
```